# Windows Store App: using XAML paths in Grid layouts (C#/XAML)

Tags: winrt-xaml

I'm starting out the design of my app by using one of the templates provided with VS2012, where you have an Image displayed next to some TextBlocks. I want the user to be able to pick a photo or similar to be the image but, in the event that they haven't done this, I want to provide a default icon.

My initial thinking was to create PNGs of the different default icons, at the different sizes that the Image icons appear at and just return those from the binding if the user hasn't specified an image, but it occurred to me that if I can use XAML Paths instead, the default icons will appear crisper because they will be drawn as vectors rather than bitmaps.

I'm not sure if that decision is a mistake but it is causing me a few headaches :-(.

The first challenge I've tried to solve is how to use binding to display either an image or the XAML Paths. My solution here was to use a Button instead of the Image, and bind Content. The Content binding returns a Canvas object that either holds the Image or the set of Paths that define the icon.

That works until I change to the snapped view, which then has smaller Image/Button elements than the unsnapped view.

So the second challenge, and the primary reason for this question, is to seek advice on how best to deal with the differing sizes of the Buttons. In the unsnapped view, the Button is 110x110. In the snapped view, the Button is 60x60. In the research I've done, the simplest way to resize the paths seems to be to use a Transform on the Canvas but since the Canvas is being returned from the Binding call, the code-behind won't necessarily know what size the parent Button is and therefore won't be able to include the Transform.

I can't use a DrawingBrush because these aren't valid in Windows Store Apps.

Is there a clean solution to this or should I go back to the simpler but slightly lower quality solution of using pre-created PNGs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I adopted in the end was to use two items - a button and an image - each wrapped in a border that allowed me to make only one of the items visible, depending on whether or not a bitmap image was available:

```
            <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="250" Height="250" Visibility="{Binding ImageIsAvailable, Converter={StaticResource HideIfTrue}}">
            <Button Content="{Binding ImageContent}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,20,0,0" Style="{StaticResource UnstyledGraphicsButtonStyle}" Width="{Binding ImageWidth210}" Height="{Binding ImageHeight210}" Foreground="white" Padding="0" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" IsEnabled="False" />
        </Border>
        <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Visibility="{Binding ImageIsAvailable, Converter={StaticResource DisplayIfTrue}}">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image250}" Stretch="{Binding Stretch250}" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
```

In this example, I'm wanting the item to be 250px by 250px. The binding for Stretch is so that I can handle images that are bigger and smaller than 250px and stretch accordingly.

For the button, the content actually comes from a declared string resource, e.g.:

```
<x:String x:Key="building">M13.982995,32.651007L13.982995,37.332006 18.665994,37.332006 18.665994,32.651007z M5.3319988,32.440006L5.3319988,37.332006 10.225996,37.332006 10.225996,32.440006z M34.665606,29.33198L34.665606,37.313 37.332797,37.313 37.332797,29.33198z M29.332198,29.33198L29.332198,37.340984 31.999405,37.340984 31.999405,29.33198z M13.923995,24.000005L13.923995,28.740005 18.665994,28.740005 18.665994,24.000005z M5.3319988,24.000005L5.3319988,28.839005 10.171997,28.839005 10.171997,24.000005z M34.665606,18.665992L34.665606,26.684976 37.332797,26.684976 37.332797,18.665992z M29.332198,18.665992L29.332198,26.644998 31.999405,26.644998 31.999405,18.665992z M13.331995,16.000003L13.331995,18.666003 15.998995,18.666003 15.998995,16.000003z M7.9989967,16.000003L7.9989967,18.666003 10.665997,18.666003 10.665997,16.000003z M26.665998,13.331976L39.998998,13.331976 39.998998,42.666973 26.665998,42.666973z M13.331995,10.666002L13.331995,13.332002 15.998995,13.332002 15.998995,10.666002z M7.9989967,10.666002L7.9989967,13.332002 10.665997,13.332002 10.665997,10.666002z M10.665997,0L13.331995,0 13.331995,5.3340011 15.998995,5.3340011 18.665994,10.666002 18.665994,18.666003 21.331993,18.666003 23.998992,21.332004 23.998992,42.667007 0,42.667007 0,21.332004 2.6659985,18.666003 5.3319988,18.666003 5.3319988,10.666002 7.9969978,5.3340011 10.665997,5.3340011z</x:String>
```

This comes from Metro Studio.

The height and width bindings are because my different SVG items have different width & height ratios so I bind to code-behind to return the correct figures for the desired size. Unfortunately because you can't pass parameters, I end up with different "ImageHeightXXX" calls for different values of XXX depending on the XAML.

Advice on how to get the string defined can be found here: http://www.jayway.com/2012/11/27/styling-windows-8-4-the-button/